# compare if values in two temp tables is same or different

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

```
**table 1**
a  b
1  1
2  2
3  3

**table 2**
a  b
1  1
2  2
```

Suppose we have two tables, I need to compare if the rows in both the tables match exactly or not. All the values of "a" in table1 should match all the values of col "a" in table2 and same for b. i.e. if you convert this into array `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]] != [[1, 1], [2, 2]].`

The returned value needs to be true or false.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: If table 1 have:  `[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]` and table 2: `[[1, 1]]` then  true  is expected or false?

Comment: Can there be NULL values? Do you consider NULL equal?

Answer (score 0):

I hopes it will help you

```
select * from table1 t1, table t2
where t1.a=t2.a and t1.b=t2.b
```

Comment: both table has same no of row? or what? what will you want in your result? what result value you want for above both table specified by you? please clarify

Comment: I have updated the question, It should return either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (TABLE1 EXCEPT TABLE2)
            THEN TRUE
            ELSE FALSE
       END AS result ;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)